# Do sub modules get stimulated independently by the solver or through the connected top level module?

Tags: system-verilog, formal-verification, yosys

I am trying to work through a [tutorial](https://zipcpu.com/tutorial/formal.html) with [example exercises](https://zipcpu.com/tutorial/class-exercises.zip) from Dan Gizzelquist.

One of those exercises (exercise 4) implements a shift register, composed by two sub module and a top module.

*Edit:* **Added Exercise source code:**

I'll post the vhdl sources here, if you prefer verilog, there are also verilog sources in the exercise-04 folder at [this](https://zipcpu.com/tutorial/class-exercises.zip) link.

lfsr_fib.vhd

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity  lfsr_fib is

    generic (LN : natural := 8;
        TAPS : std_logic_vector(LN-1 downto 0) := x"2d";
        INITIAL_FILL : std_logic_vector(LN-1 downto 0) := x"01");

    port (i_clk, i_reset, i_ce, i_in : in std_logic;
        o_bit : out std_logic := INITIAL_FILL(0));

end entity lfsr_fib;

architecture behavior of lfsr_fib is
    signal  sreg : std_logic_vector(LN-1 downto 0) := INITIAL_FILL;
begin


process(i_clk)
begin
    if (rising_edge(i_clk)) then
        if (i_reset = '1') then
            sreg <= INITIAL_FILL;
        elsif (i_ce = '1') then
            sreg(LN-2 downto 0) <= sreg(LN-1 downto 1);
            sreg(LN-1) <= (xor (sreg and TAPS)) xor i_in;
        end if;
    end if;
end process;

process(sreg)
begin
    o_bit <= sreg(0);
end process;


end behavior;
```

dblpipe.vhd

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity dblpipe is

    port (i_clk, i_ce, i_data : in std_logic;
        o_data : out std_logic := '0');

end entity dblpipe;

architecture behavior of dblpipe is
    component lfsr_fib
      port(i_clk, i_reset, i_ce, i_in : in std_logic;
        o_bit : out std_logic);
    end component;

    signal  a_data, b_data : std_logic;
begin
----
----

one: lfsr_fib port map (
    i_clk => i_clk,
    i_reset => '0',
    i_ce => i_ce,
    i_in => i_data,
    o_bit => a_data);

two: lfsr_fib port map (
    i_clk => i_clk,
    i_reset => '0',
    i_ce => i_ce,
    i_in => i_data,
    o_bit => b_data);

process(a_data, b_data)
begin
    o_data <= a_data xor b_data;
end process;

----
----
end behavior;
```

formal properties file:

```
`default_nettype    none
//
module dblpipe_vhd(i_clk, i_ce, o_data);
    input   wire    i_clk;
    input   wire    i_ce;
    input   wire    o_data;

`ifdef FORMAL
// Your goal: to get the following assertion to pass
//

    // assume(one.sreg = two.sreg);
    // assert(one.sreg == two.sreg);

    always @(*)
    begin
        assert(o_data == 1'b0);
    end

    always @(*)
    begin
        if(i_clk)
            begin
                assume(one.i_clk);
                assume(two.i_clk);
            end
        else
            begin
                assume(!one.i_clk);
                assume(!two.i_clk);
            end
    end

    //Trigger a counter example at step 18 - to check if the assumptions made where applied
    // always @(posedge i_clk)
    //  if(f_time >= 18)
    //      assert(f_time < 18);


`endif
endmodule

bind dblpipe dblpipe_vhd copy (.*);
```

sby control script:

```
[options]
mode prove

[engines]
smtbmc
# abc pdr
# abc pdr
# aiger avy
# aiger suprove

[script]
read -vhdl   lfsr_fib.vhd
read -vhdl   dblpipe.vhd
read -formal dblpipe_vhd.sv
prep -top dblpipe

[files]
lfsr_fib.vhd
dblpipe.vhd
dblpipe_vhd.sv
```

### Related Question 1:

Playing around with different assertations led to the following K-Induction Trace:

[image: K-Induction Trace]

My questions is, why does the trace show that the clock of the submodules are ticking while the top-level clock does not?

Even adding the following code did not get the clocks to tick simultaneously:

```
always @(*)
begin
    if(i_clk)
        begin
            assume(one.i_clk);
            assume(two.i_clk);
        end
    else
        begin
            assume(!one.i_clk);
            assume(!two.i_clk);
        end
end
```

However i_ce is apparently connected somehow as it is in sync amongst all modules:
[i_ce Traces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0t5r.png)

### Related Question 2

And why is the solution to the problem to *assert* that both sregs are equal instead of to *assume* that they are equal?

As we are defining which inputs shall be taken for granted for me it sounds more like assume should be used in this case.

```
always @(*)
    assert(one.sreg == two.sreg);
```

instead of:

```
always @(*)
    assume(one.sreg = two.sreg);
```

### Related Question 3

Can somebody explain to me why the input data is not wired-up in the wrapper module? This way I cannot see what data is fed into the top-level module in the trace view... But if I add it to the module definition it still stays always 0 in the trace file.

```
module dblpipe_vhd(i_clk, i_ce, o_data);
input   wire    i_clk;
input   wire    i_ce;
input   wire    o_data;
```

Most questions that I had in the past could be solved by reading the available documentation again and again, but regarding these questions I just could not find a solution on my own.

Comment: Unfortunately you have not provided enough information to answer your question. Please create an example which could be cut-n-pasted into a simulation environment and  shows your issues. Most likely clock generator was created for a leaf module instead of the top module.

Comment: It would make the question more readable if you pasted the code from the exercise.

Comment: It would also be better practice to make a separate post for each question you have. This increases your chances of getting them answered.

Comment: Thanks for your advices, I added the source code as requested. I left it out before to avoid an excessively long post and just added the link to the example. 
@TudorTimi Normally I would agree, but in this case all questions regard the same exercise so I feel like it would be more confusing to post them separately.

Comment: It seems like you didn't post the original files from the exercises, but ones with your edits too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### On question 1

The trace you're seeing might have some kind of tool bug which causes it to not set the value of `dblpipe_vhd .i_clk` properly. I say this, because it seems that your assertion is firing. The tool probably sees that there is no clocked logic directly under `dblpipe_vhd` and treats the clock as redundant.

The tool (and other formal verification tools as well) infers clocks automatically and handles them differently to "regular" signals that describe logic. The `assumes` you wrote for the clocks will probably not do anything.

(I'm not that familiar with `sby`, but I can imagine that it actually uses the `smt_clock` signal to clock the logic and the other clocks are there just for debug purposes.)

### On question 2

IMO, for the assertion on `o_data` to pass, it should be enough to `assume` that the two LSFRs start out from the same state. Since you never apply reset, the tool is free to choose the initial state. I'm guessing the author is trying to make a point of this.

No idea why you would want to do proofs without applying reset first. Reset signals are there to ensure predictable start states. You'll never really use them without resetting them first.

### On question 3

`dblpipe_vhd` is not the top module. `dblpipe` is. An instance of `dblpipe_vhd` called `copy` is added under `dblpipe` by the `bind` statement. It only asserts against `o_data`, so it only needs that signal.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So you mean that sub-modules should be seen as a unit with the top level module. 
The thing is that then I just cannot understand how it is even possible that the s_regs in the two sub modules ever reach different values if they are filled with the same exact values (i_data). It looks like the sub-modules are not simulated at all with regard of the top-module and its port mappings.

Comment: Do you have any clue regarding question 2?

Comment: The LSFRs can start with different values, since they're not reset.

Comment: The strategy for reset handling in sby and Dan's writing on the topic of initial state are things I never really got. In other formal verification tools reset would be treated as "special" (kind of like clock is "special"). They would ask the user to specify the reset signal(s) and would do proofs after applying it.

Comment: The top port mappings are adhered to, because you'll see that both LSFRs get the exact same input data stream and enable.

Comment: "The LSFRs can start with different values, since they're not reset."

I thought that the LSFRs actually ARE reset:
`signal  sreg : std_logic_vector(LN-1 downto 0) := INITIAL_FILL;`

This code line is taken from the filter module and clearly states that the registers are initialized with an initial value as far as I understand.

Comment: Can you suggest me some other formal verification tools that you enjoyed to use and find to be easy to use?

Comment: The initial value will only be used for simulation, not for formal verification. This is surely documented somewhere in sby. I'm not sure whether there's a tool switch that makes it consider initial values, too. This seems like it would be useful for FPGA-only designs, where initial values are honored.

Comment: I've used OneSpin 360 MV and JasperGold, but they're both commercial tools.